# How to Subtract Values from Matching Columns in Two Different Pandas DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
df_t = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['BusinessUtc','Horizon','EvaluationUtc','BZ','Value'])
date = pd.to_datetime('2023-01-01 00:00:00')
day = timedelta(days = 1)
date1 = date
date2 = date - day
date3 = date2 -day
date4 = date3 -day
Horizon = 'D-1'
BZ = ['NO4','NO4','NO4','NO4','NO1','NO1','NO1','NO1','NO5','NO5','NO5','NO5']
Values = [1301.681, 1271.479,1460.043, 1302.357,3412.155, 3611.549, 4042.706, 3756.527,1462.085, 4042.706, 3756.527,1462.085]
df_t['EvaluationUtc'] = [date1,date2,date3,date4,date1,date2,date3,date4,date1,date2,date3,date4]
df_t['BusinessUtc'] = date
df_t['Horizon'] = Horizon
df_t['EvaluationUtc'] = [date1,date2,date3,date4,date1,date2,date3,date4,date1,date2,date3,date4]
df_t['BZ'] = BZ
df_t['Value'] = Values

df2 = df_t.drop(index = [1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10,11])
```

I want to subtract the `'Value'` from each row for matching `'BZ'` in `df_t` with the corresponding `'Value'` from the second `DataFrame` `df2`.

So for example NO4's Value **= 1301.681** from df_t subtracted from each of the NO4 values in df2, then the same for the other BZ's. This can be stored in a new `DataFrame`.

Comment: The question is unclear, can you provide the exact expected output? Do you want to subtract only the rows matching on all columns? Or just on BZ?

Comment: edited to make clearer

Comment: OK, then a simple `merge`/`map` should be enough: `out = df_t.assign(Value=df_t['Value'].sub(df_t['BZ'].map(df2.set_index('BZ')['Value'])))`

Comment: This only works for the first BZ, the cells for the other BZ's only contain nan values

Comment: It's not the case with the current example, can you provide an example that gives you NaNs?

Comment: it was because the index in my version of ´df_2´ was not reset. Is there a way to ignore the index without having to reset it when the calculation is made?

Comment: Can you update the question to show exactly what `df2` looks like?

Comment: ran it again and it worked without giving any Nan's. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify columns for corresponding match between both DataFrames, convert to index and subtract:

```
cols = ['BusinessUtc','Horizon','BZ']
df = df_t.set_index(cols)['Value'].sub(df2.set_index(cols)['Value']).reset_index()
print (df)
   BusinessUtc Horizon   BZ     Value
0   2023-01-01     D-1  NO1     0.000
1   2023-01-01     D-1  NO1   199.394
2   2023-01-01     D-1  NO1   630.551
3   2023-01-01     D-1  NO1   344.372
4   2023-01-01     D-1  NO4     0.000
5   2023-01-01     D-1  NO4   -30.202
6   2023-01-01     D-1  NO4   158.362
7   2023-01-01     D-1  NO4     0.676
8   2023-01-01     D-1  NO5     0.000
9   2023-01-01     D-1  NO5  2580.621
10  2023-01-01     D-1  NO5  2294.442
11  2023-01-01     D-1  NO5     0.000
```

If need match by one column (and add new subtract column) use mapping:

```
df = df_t.assign(sub = df_t['Value'].sub(df_t['BZ'].map(df2.set_index('BZ')['Value'])))
print (df)
  BusinessUtc Horizon EvaluationUtc   BZ     Value       sub
0   2023-01-01     D-1    2023-01-01  NO4  1301.681     0.000
1   2023-01-01     D-1    2022-12-31  NO4  1271.479   -30.202
2   2023-01-01     D-1    2022-12-30  NO4  1460.043   158.362
3   2023-01-01     D-1    2022-12-29  NO4  1302.357     0.676
4   2023-01-01     D-1    2023-01-01  NO1  3412.155     0.000
5   2023-01-01     D-1    2022-12-31  NO1  3611.549   199.394
6   2023-01-01     D-1    2022-12-30  NO1  4042.706   630.551
7   2023-01-01     D-1    2022-12-29  NO1  3756.527   344.372
8   2023-01-01     D-1    2023-01-01  NO5  1462.085     0.000
9   2023-01-01     D-1    2022-12-31  NO5  4042.706  2580.621
10  2023-01-01     D-1    2022-12-30  NO5  3756.527  2294.442
11  2023-01-01     D-1    2022-12-29  NO5  1462.085     0.000
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, the expected output is unclear.

I really you need to broadcast the value for a set of columns, then a left-[`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) seems most appropriate (it will maintain the original structure):

```
cols = ['BusinessUtc','Horizon','BZ']
out = df_t.assign(Value=df_t['Value'].sub(df_t.drop(columns='Value')
                                              .merge(df2, on=cols, how='left')['Value'],
                                          fill_value=0))
```

Output:

```
   BusinessUtc Horizon EvaluationUtc   BZ     Value
0   2023-01-01     D-1    2023-01-01  NO4     0.000
1   2023-01-01     D-1    2022-12-31  NO4   -30.202
2   2023-01-01     D-1    2022-12-30  NO4   158.362
3   2023-01-01     D-1    2022-12-29  NO4     0.676
4   2023-01-01     D-1    2023-01-01  NO1     0.000
5   2023-01-01     D-1    2022-12-31  NO1   199.394
6   2023-01-01     D-1    2022-12-30  NO1   630.551
7   2023-01-01     D-1    2022-12-29  NO1   344.372
8   2023-01-01     D-1    2023-01-01  NO5     0.000
9   2023-01-01     D-1    2022-12-31  NO5  2580.621
10  2023-01-01     D-1    2022-12-30  NO5  2294.442
11  2023-01-01     D-1    2022-12-29  NO5     0.000
```